# jquery stops working when navigating backwards through views in mvc 4

Tags: c#, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have a simple login screen which uses ajax to login to the system, the css and scripts are all loaded using bundles.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="target-densitydpi=device-dpi; width=device-width;initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0; user-scalable=0;" />
<title>@ViewBag.Title</title>
@Styles.Render("~/Content/css")   

</head>
<body>

@RenderBody()
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
</body>
</html>
```

All of my scripts work perfectly on page load, but once i have logged in and click on the logout button, i get redirected to the login screen but none of my scripts no longer work. i think this is because of the way i am redirecting the user once they have clicked on the logout button, looking at the URL it still says that im on the ~/Home/Logout instead of the ~/login/index.

here is the code im using to logout my users.

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Home";
}

<div data-role="page">
    <div>
        <div data-role="navbar">
            <ul>
                <li>@Html.ActionLink("Logout", "Logout",  "Home"  , null, null)</li>
                <li><a href="#" id="btnFilter">Filter</a></li>
            </ul>

            <div id="filter" style="background-color:#F6F6F6;">
                <div style="padding: 0px 5px;">
                    <select id="ddlAudits">
                        <option value="-1">Select Inspection</option>
                        @foreach (var i in ViewBag.AuditDropDown)
                        {
                            <option value="@i.AuditID" >@i.AuditTitle</option>
                        }
                    </select>

                    <select id="ddlAccounts">
                        <option value="-1">Select Account</option>
                        @foreach (var i in ViewBag.AccountDropDown)
                        {
                            <option value="@i.AccountID" >@i.AccountName</option>
                        }
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="DivAccounts">
        </div>

</div>
```

I have tried setting the logout button on my home page to

```
<a href="~/">Logout</a>
```

but the scripts still fail to load once i am redirected back to the login screen. im having a little difficulty understanding this as ive only been doing MVC for a little over a month.

and here is my action which is being called with ajax to logout the users

```
public ActionResult Logout()
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie("ctUserID", false);
        FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
        return Redirect("~/");
    }
```

Any help / advice will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: try `return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");`

Comment: By clicking on my logout button on my home screen, it does redirect me to my login screen, but the URL remains as ~/Home/Logout. and when i look at the scripts that have been loaded into the page, the ~/home scripts are still there. i would like my ~/Login scripts to be loaded.

Comment: Please include your Login action

Answer (score 0):

I found a way around it, dont know if it was the best way but instead of using the _layout view, i just created separate views and included my bundles at the top of all the pages. now everything works perfectly.